# reference request for construction of expanders

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, expanders

I'm looking for a good exposition of the explicit constructive proof of the existence of expander graph families due to Reingold Vadhan and Wigderson.  Arora/Barak has a chapter on it, but i find it to be full of typos, more serious errors, and other annoying choices (not to knock AB -- I like it generally).  I just started reading the original RVW paper, but I was wondering if there are other good sources.

Comment: The expander chapter in Vadhan's pseudorandomness monograph? https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/pseudorandomness/expanders.pdf

Answer (score 8):

You can look at [this survey](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~mihail/LINIALexpsurvey.pdf) by Hoory, Linial, and Wigderson [1]. Chapter 9, specifically (p. 508) is on the zigzag product.

`9.The zig-zag product
  9.1.   Introduction
  9.2.   Construction of an expander family using zig-zag
  9.3.   Definition and analysis of the zig-zag product
  9.4.   Entropy analysis
  9.5.   An application to complexity theory: SL=L`

---

[1] Hoory, Shlomo, Nathan Linial, and Avi Wigderson. *Expander graphs and their applications.* Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society 43.4 (2006): 439-561.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some additional notes: lecture [notes](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dieter/Courses/2006s-CS880/Scribes/06/lecture06.ps) by Dieter van Melkebeek , [notes](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs359g/lecture17.pdf) from Luca Trevisan's course on expanders.